# Позиционирование блока

Tags: html, css

На странице блок, в котором расположены элементы управления слайдером, смещается влево.

[image]

Слайдер на странице стоит вот этот [SlidesJS](http://slidesjs.com/), мой слайдер сделан по этому [примеру](http://slidesjs.com/examples/linking/).
Блок `<ul class="pagination"></ul>` отрисовывается скрптом слайдера.
У меня для него заданы такие стилевые 
свойства

```
.pagination{
    background: url('../images/controls_background.png') no-repeat;
    width: 109px;
    height: 29px;
    padding: 20px 20px 0 35px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 38px;
    position: relative;
```

}
но блок все равно сдвинут влево, вот [моя верстка](http://web-portfolio1.narod.ru/index6/index.html).
Предполагаю, надо задать свойства не самому блоку, а родительскому элементу, но не могу разобраться, что именно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float: left
```

*но блок все равно сдвинут влево*

Действительно, чего это он?..

Comment: а, большое спасибо) совсем уже глаза замылились)